# How to sort a list object by the other list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, compare

I have the follow Objects:

```
public class Processitems{
   private String priority;
   private Date date;
   private Integer status;
}

public class OrderItems {
   private String orderItem1;
   private String orderItem2;
}
```

orderItem1, orderItem2 is "priority" or "date" or "status"
Now I must sort `List<ProcessItem>` by conditions of OrderItems. I mean if orderItem1 = "priority" then sort `List<ProcessItem>` by priority, if orderItem = "date" then sort List by date,... and if sort by orderItem1 is unavailable then sort by orderItem2 . How could I use `Comperator.comparing(orderItem1).thencomparing(orderItem2)` ?

Comment: You can use  Comparator for that . Check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/

Comment: What do you mean by "if sort by orderItem1 is unavailable then sort by orderItem2"? In what scenario is "sort by orderItem1" not available?

Comment: @Joni  If the orderItem1 is null then use orderItem2.

Comment: @Joni : Eg: orderItem1 = "priority" and priority has two value: HIGH and NORMAL, and all priority of List<Processitem> is HIGH , in that case I need sort by orderItem2

Comment: ok then my answer should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is add a method to `OrderItems` that builds the appropriate `Comparator` object for you. Let's call it `getComparator`.

Since you have two fields you want to sort by - orderItem1 and orderItem2 - it's useful to create a helper method that creates a comparator for any field you want to pass in.

Then you can use it to create two comparators and compose them together, or do whatever you want.

```
public class OrderItems {
    private String orderItem1;
    private String orderItem2;

    private Comparator<Processitems> createComparatorForField(String field) {
        switch (field) {
            case "priority": return Comparator.comparing(p -> p.priority);
            case "date": return Comparator.comparing(p -> p.date);
            case "status": return Comparator.comparing(p -> p.status);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(field);
    }
    
    Comparator<Processitems> getComparator() {
        if (orderItem1 != null) {
          Comparator<Processitems> order1 = createComparatorForField(orderItem1);
          Comparator<Processitems> order2 = createComparatorForField(orderItem2);
          return order1.thenComparing(order2);
        }
        else return createComparatorForField(orderItem2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can take use of java.lang.reflect.Field for your case:

```
// OrderItem  can be detrmined at runtime based on your logic
String orderItem = "priority"; 

Comparator<Processitems> comparator = new Comparator<Processitems>(){
    public int compare(Processitems p1, Processitems p2){
        try {
            Field processItem = p1.getClass().getField(orderItem);
            Comparable<Object> comparablep1
                = (Comparable<Object>) processItem.get(p1);
            Comparable<Object> comparablep2
                = (Comparable<Object>) processItem.get(p2);

            return comparablep1.compareTo(comparablep2);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                          "No field present with " + orderItem, e);
        }
    };
}
```